# Infinite intersection of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, induction, banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Given are Banach spaces $B_p\subset C( \mathbb{R})$ with norm $||\cdot||_p = ||g_p \cdot||_\infty$ where $f_p$ is defined via $f_p(x)=(1+|x|^2)^{-p/2}$ and where $||\cdot||_\infty$ is the usual supremum norm. These Banach spaces are defined by

$$B_p:=\lbrace f\in C(\mathbb{R}) : ||f||_p <\infty \rbrace$$

Is it true that

$$B=\bigcap_{p>0} B_p$$

is itself a Banach space for some properly chosen norm?

In a paper I'm reading, $B$ is called an inductive limit. However the definition of inductive limit is a bit different..

Comment: No. I principle it is not a Banach space, but a Frechet one. Just take the coarsest linear topology making all the $\| f \|_p$ continuous.

Comment: An intersection is a *projective* limit.

Comment: @adrián-gonzález-pérez Could you be more specific about the coarsest linear topology w.r.t. to this norm $||\cdot||_p$.

Comment: A net $f_\alpha$ converge to f iff $\| f - f_\alpha \|_p$ goes to $0$ for every $p$.

Comment: @adrián-gonzález-pérez Thank you for your comment. Since another question was to characterize the dual of this space $B$ : Do you know how this is usually done or if you can provide a reference in which this is done?